# Different results in different mysql server versions - Hibernate API

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA (Hibernate) with spring boot project. The problem is that the same application is running in different servers with different mysql-server version. The query from ORM is:

```
select
        distinct distributo0_.id as id1_0_,
        distributo0_.address as address2_0_,
        distributo0_.city as city3_0_,
        distributo0_.email as email4_0_,
        distributo0_.first_name as first_na5_0_,
        distributo0_.last_name as last_nam6_0_,
        distributo0_.phone as phone7_0_,
        distributo0_.country as country8_0_,
        distributo0_.created as created9_0_,
        distributo0_.latitue as latitue10_0_,
        distributo0_.longitude as longitu11_0_,
        distributo0_.name as name12_0_,
        distributo0_.postal_code as postal_13_0_,
        distributo0_.status as status14_0_,
        distributo0_.type as type15_0_,
        distributo0_.last_update as last_up16_0_,
        distributo0_1_.merchandiser_id as merchand1_1_ 
    from
        distributor distributo0_ 
    left outer join
        distributor_merchandiser distributo0_1_ 
            on distributo0_.id=distributo0_1_.distributor_id 
    where
        distributo0_.name=? limit ?
```

it should return two results based on distributor name - for example: the name is "ГА ДИСТРОЙ". 
It works on:

**mariadb-server 5.5.56-2.el7**

**mysql-server 5.1.73-7.el6**

and not working on 
**mysql-community-server 5.7.20-1.el6** ( there is no results for the same DB)

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same collation on all servers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html

Comment: Limit without order by is fairly meaningless. Incidentally, one of the joys of aliases is that they can be short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're running a query with a LIMIT clause, but without an ORDER BY clause. Not providing the default sort columns and their direction, will use the default sorting method, so the results can be unpredictable and that's probably what changes the outcome in both servers.

I would recommend adding an ORDER BY clause in the query on both servers and testing again.

Also, try to compare the charsets of the tables in both servers. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` on the relevant tables and compare the charset. It should be the same, otherwise strange things can happen when comparing the queries.

Also, are you sure the data is the same in both servers?

Comment: Thanks, i added to query ORDER BY, but still doesn't work.. any other suggestions ?

Comment: The database is absolutely the same. Both tables in the servers are using ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=742 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Now I noticed that the query doesn't work with Cyrillic language.. If the distributor name is in English, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much guys! I learned some new things. The problem was related with collation on the database. After I changed the collation and set

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Everything works.

Comment: MySQL's utf8 is not actually UTF8. You can't use 4-byte characters with it (like the new emojis in recent years). Check this https://www.eversql.com/mysql-utf8-vs-utf8mb4-whats-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf8mb4/